# mousemove animation with transition lags in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a bunch of small particles which I would like to move slightly when mouse moves. Their positions are relative to their parents. The movement is quite as I wanted in chrome, very smooth and subtle but lags a lot in firefox.

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/donomron/mwmcn6tf/1/) is the jsfiddle simplified version of what I'm trying to do. Open it in both chrome and firefox and compare the movements.

This is the javascript code which is using jquery mousemove()

```
var centerX = window.innerWidth/2,
    centerY = window.innerHeight/2;

    $('body').mousemove(function(e){
  var clientX = e.clientX,
      clientY = e.clientY,
      amountMovedX = (centerX - clientX)/20,
      amountMovedY = (centerY - clientY)/20;
  if(clientX > centerX){
    amountMovedX *= -1;
  }

            $('#rect1').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*1.1+'px,'+amountMovedY+'px, 0) rotate(-15deg)');
                    $('#rect2').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*1.8+'px,'+amountMovedY*1.4+'px, 0)');
                    $('#rect3').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*0.8+'px,'+amountMovedY*1.9+'px, 0) rotate(30deg)');
                    $('#rect4').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*1.6+'px,'+amountMovedY*0.7+'px, 0)');

                    $('#rect5').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*-1.7+'px,'+amountMovedY*1.1+'px, 0) rotate(30deg');
                    $('#rect6').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*-0.8+'px,'+amountMovedY*1.9+'px, 0)');
                    $('#rect7').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*-1.3+'px,'+amountMovedY*0.9+'px, 0) rotate(-30deg');
                    $('#rect8').css('transform','translate3d('+amountMovedX*-0.5+'px,'+amountMovedY*1.5+'px, 0) rotate(-15deg)');
        });
```

I think this has to do with transition of particles because if I remove transition properties, animations are the same in both browsers but I need this transition time and easing because of some other movement of these particles. So any ideas what might cause this?

And also if there is something weird or wrong about my code, feel free to correct it. I'm eager to learn more as fast as possible.

Answer (score 0):

There's a magic function, which solves those kind of problems:
http://underscorejs.org/#throttle

Or you can go about using requestAnimationFrame like in here:
[How to use requestAnimationFrame in mousemove event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21249493/how-to-use-requestanimationframe-in-mousemove-event)

Example with throttling:

```
var th=_.throttle(function(opts){//opts={x:...,y:...}
 //do your stuff here
},100);

$(document).on('mousemove',function(e){
 th({x:e.pageX,y:e.pageY});
});
```

Comment: Well, since you posted this as an answer, please add an example using `throttle`. Unfortunately, there's no way to "move" an answer to comments, it can be only deleted as not an answer.